# HTML5 Drag-and-Drop: How do I target the cloned AND original elements?

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop

I want to apply a class name to the "ghost" element being dragged, not the original element that was cloned. Here is the function I have in place for the `dragstart` event:

```
function dragStart(event) {
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.getAttribute('id'));
    console.log(event);
    console.log('Dragging...');
    $(event.currentTarget).addClass('dragging');
    return true;
}
```

The `$(event.currentTarget).addClass('dragging');` line adds the `.dragging` class to the original element but not the cloned, dragging element.

How do I properly target both?

**EDIT**

Looking to handle this with native HTML5 as much as possible. Prefer not to use a jQuery plugin.

Comment: While I have not actually done anything like this before, to me it sounds like the "ghost" element you refer to is an image/canvas that can be overwritten with `event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(image, xOffset, yOffset);`. This is based on information from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#dragfeedback).

Comment: Absolutely true, but I'd love to be able to style the cloned or "ghost" element and not replace it altogether... Sounds like it may not be possible.

Comment: Have you tried duplicating the target object (in JavaScript), adding your class to the duplicate, and then pass that into the `setDragImage` method?  While it states that the first parameter is an image, I think it really means "what DOM element to use for the generated image".

Comment: You're using jQuery already and you don't want to use a plugin. Does that mean you can't use more jQuery? You should really not use jQuery in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an avid JavaScript scripter, but i stumbled upon this page while trying to find something for you, it might be what you need, specifically the proxy drag version:

http://threedubmedia.com/demo/drag/

```
$('#demo6_box')
        .bind('dragstart',function( event ){
                if ( !$(event.target).is('.handle') ) return false;
                return $( this ).css('opacity',.5)
                        .clone().addClass('active')
                        .insertAfter( this );
                })
        .bind('drag',function( event ){
                $( event.dragProxy ).css({
                        top: event.offsetY,
                        left: event.offsetX
                        });
                })
        .bind('dragend',function( event ){
                $( event.dragProxy ).remove();
                $( this ).animate({
                        top: event.offsetY,
                        left: event.offsetX,
                        opacity: 1
                        })
                });
```

This is all jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do this with as much native HTML5 as possible.

Comment: I see no problem with including jquery, it's so powerful, and simply a lot easier than normal javascript. But your question, your rules.

Comment: It's not a problem at all—I actually am including it—I'd just prefer to do this with as much native functionality as possible.

Comment: Okay, i suppose every developer works by his own standards, good luck anyhow (i was going to place a smiley, but then i realized this is a serious Q&A board)

Answer (score 7):

Add the class on the original element, then remove it after dragging starts ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/Ect4B/)):

```
function dragStart(event) {
    var el = $(this);

    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.getAttribute('id'));

    el.addClass('dragging');
    setTimeout(function() { el.removeClass('dragging'); }, 0);
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, and it might be the best way to get around it. There's definitely that flash at the beginning as soon as you start dragging, but I suspect some CSS tweaks can handle that.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but what you need to do is create/use a visible element (or image/canvas, etc) per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#setDragImage.28.29

So, you could take your currently dragging element (`this` in the event context usually), clone it, add it to the dom (ensuring it is "visible", aka not `display: none` or `visibility:hidden`) and you could then apply a class to it so you can target the dragged item itself in css. Then, add that element as the first argument to `e.dataTransfer.setDragImage()` and the browser will use that instead.

Just remember to remove it later (`dragend`) or hide it in some way.

Here's a fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/6TDvz/

Answer (score 1):

From this line of code:

```
event.originalEvent
```

seems that you are using jquery? So just consider that jquery make things much easier and is cross browser compatible.

HTML5 native and jquery method (using just javascript) implementing drag are almost the same. HTML5 has added only drag events but nothing more to drag and drop methods:

**with no jquery:**

```
function dragStart(event) {
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target);//JUST ELEMENT references is ok here NO ID
    console.log(event);
    console.log('Dragging...');

    var clone = event.target.cloneNode(true);
    event.target.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    event.target.ghostDragger = clone;//SET A REFERENCE TO THE HELPER

    $(clone).addClass('dragging');//NOW YOU HAVE A CLONE ELEMENT JUST USE this and remove on drag stop
    return true;
}

function dragging(event){
  var clone = event.target.ghostDragger;
  //here set clone LEFT and TOP from event mouse moves
}
//ON STOP REMOVE HELPER ELEMENT
function stopDrag(event){
  var clone = event.target.ghostDragger;
  clone.parentNode.removeChild(clone);
}
```

**With jquery:**

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ 
 helper: "clone", //EVEN here you can set the helper you want by defining a funcition
 start:function(event, ui){
   ui.helper.addClass('yourclass');
 }
});
```

Althoug I will suggest using jquery ui for draging. With it you can personalize the drag helper as you need.

Comment: for me in chrome this styles the original element.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but the following works for me, giving both the original and the dragged text a yellow background (by setting the class).  Perhaps there's something in your specific situation that's giving you a "ghost" copy.  Or maybe it has something to do with the little bit of jQuery you're already using.  All I can say is that in trying to recreate your problem, my simple test case actually works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drag Test</title>
    <script>
      function startDrag(event) {
        var orig = document.getElementById('original');
        var dt = event.dataTransfer;

        orig.className += 'dragging';

        dt.effectAllowed = 'move';
        dt.setData('text/plain', 'This text may be dragged');
      }
    </script>

    <style>
      .dragging {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="original"  draggable="true" ondragstart="startDrag(event);">
      This text may be dragged.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I want to apply a class name to the "ghost" element being dragged, not
>   the original element that was cloned

Well, with normal drag and drop there is no original vs cloned element, there is just the element being dragged. Without seeing the rest of the drag and drop implementation, there is no way to give you an answer. We don't know what "event" is being called. If your `dragStart` event is the `HTML5 ondragstart event` then [this article](http://help.dottoro.com/ljpncnwi.php) might help you out. But if it is a custom event created by jQuery or some other framework then there is no way for anyone to tell you how to get the original vs. cloned element unless you share the rest of your code.

If you don't want to rely on jQuery then you will have to write the entire drag and drop functionality from scratch. Here are a few tutorials on how to do so:

[JavaScript Drag and Drop Tutorial](http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx)

[Drag & Drop Sortable Lists w/ JavaScript](http://tool-man.org/examples/sorting.html)

[HTML5 Drag & Drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_draganddrop.asp)

If I could make a suggestion it would be to stick w/ jQuery. Making a cross-browser compatible drag and drop system from scratch will require a good amount of time. If you share the rest of your code then I could try to help you out with a more specific answer.